# Sharepoint 2010: List view to always show last friday's data

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom-list, filter

I've been working on this issue forever now...Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a custom list where people add some info. I crated 2 views to view items added today and yesterday. Now I'm trying to figure out how to create a view that will always show items added last friday no matter what day of the week I look at the view... I tried following and it didn't work for me:

- Filtered "Created" column where it =[Today]-3, which didn't work because I can use it only on Monday
- Filtered "Created" column and used following formula:

> IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=1,[Created]-3,IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=2,[Created]-4,IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=3,[Created]-5,IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=4,[Created]-6,IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=5,[Created]-7,IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=6,[Created]-1,[Created]-2))))))

this formula always gave me "Filter Value is not in supported date format", so i tried using "text(above formula,"mm/dd/yyyy") and it didn't work either

- Because of the format I decided to create an extra column that simply converted "Created" into text...so =Text([Created],"mm/dd/yyyy"). And then I tried to filter newly created column with the above formula...it didn't work...
- I tried using another formula in the filter, and got another date format error...However, I like this formula the best as it pretty much checks for day for the week, and if it's not Friday, than does calculation...

> =IF(OR([Today]=1,[Today]=2,[Today]=3,[Today]=4,[Today]=6,[Today]=7),[Today]+(5-[Today])-7,[Today]-6)
>   
>   I'm looking for some ideas or suggestions to try. Again **the goal is to be able to pull last friday's data any day of the week**

Thank you in advance for your assistance and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the filter doesn't support any advanced formulars. The only formulars are today +/- some days.

You may solve your problem by creating a calculated column `CreatedWeekday` as `WEEKDAY([Created],2)`

Then on you view you can use the filter:
`CreatedWeekday` Equals `5`
AND
`Created` Greater than `[Today]-8`
AND
`Created` Less than `[Today]`

Comment: best solution so far...Not ideal, considering that I have couple more filters to play with, but better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can point you in the right direction:

http://www.petestilgoe.com/tag/calculated-column/

http://www.myriadtech.com.au/blog/Alana/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8

I would go with creating a calculated column like so:

Week end (Friday)

> =[Created]+(5–WEEKDAY([due date],2))

then subtract 7 in the filter

Comment: It doesn't work: when I create a column with the above formula it calculates just fine. But when I add a filter for "Created" column with the formula [New Column]-7 I either get an error about wrong date format OR if i tried to convert the column to date there's no values returned what so ever....Any other suggestions? please?

Comment: I also trieed following formula: IF(WEEKNUM([Today])-WEEKNUM([Created])=1,IF(WEEKDAY([Created],2)=6,"Last Friday","hide"),"hide"). It doesn't look like Sharepoint likes WEEKNUM